# Setting cornerRadius of layer for a view embedeed in stack view gives unexpected results

Tags: ios, realm

`ModernBoldButton` is a subclass of `UIButton`, here is a snippet of it:

```
private func commonInit() {
    insertSubview(blurView, at: 0)
    if let imageView = imageView {
        bringSubviewToFront(imageView)
    }
    if let titleLabel = titleLabel {
        bringSubviewToFront(titleLabel)
    }
    backgroundColor = .clear
    clipsToBounds = true
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    layer.cornerRadius = bounds.width / 2
}
```

I have four UIButton's embedeed in stack view and as you can see on the screenshot, all of the buttons have incorrect shapes, they should look like a circle.

I suspect that I should set the `cornerRadius` somewhere else in my code, but where?

[image]

Comment: In order for them to look like a circle, your bounds must be a square. It appears that this is not the case for your buttons (the width is larger than the height). Other than that, you're setting it in the right place.

Comment: That was it! I had to play with constraints a little more, just another day when UIStackView is a PIA

Comment: Glad that helped. Posted it as an answer to help closing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for them to look like a circle, your bounds must be a *square*. It appears that this is not the case for your buttons (the width is larger than the height).

You could add some constraints to your buttons in order to maintain a 1/1 ratio.

Other than that, you're setting it in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Rounding to `with/2` will completely rounded top and bottom sides (eye shape )
Rounding to `height/2` will completely rounded left and right sides (like this `()`)

So if you want a circle, you need to make sure both `width` and `height` sizes are the same like a square.

In order to doo it automatically, you can use autolayout and the stackView will take care of the sizing:

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

Make sure to do it just once to avoid duplications.